# How to fix Unknown RTP codec 126 received on aterisk?

Tags: sip, asterisk, voip, voicemail

Hello Asterisk guys out there, im having trouble lately on our server. Before my everything is fine then suddenly i have this error of

res_rtp_asterisk.c:4100 ast_rtp_read: Unknown RTP codec 126 received from 'X.X.X.X:55066'

Cant dial my voicemail
"

```
Sip.conf------------------------
[johndoe]

type=friend 
secret=Jonddoe
directmedia=no               
disallow=all
nat=force_rport
allow=gsm                    
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=g722
allow=g726
allow=h261
allow=h263
allow=h263p
allow=h264
mailbox=1234@default


Extensions.conf--------------------
exten => 1000,1,Dial(SIP/johndoe,30)
exten => 1000,2,VoiceMail(1234@default)
exten => 1000,3,PlayBack(vm-goodbye)
exten => 1000,4,HangUp()

exten => *1,1,VoiceMailMain(1234@default)




Voicemail.conf------------------------
1234 => 1234, johndoe, john@doe.com
```

"

Hope you guys can give some insights and help me on this,

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as it's not programming related.

Answer (score 2):

This is a warning, meaning your sip client offers a codec not known by asterisk. Happens with softphones all the time, usually involving video OFFER. It's not the reason why you can't access voicemail. Check your dialplan.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Counterpath Bria/X-Lite, reach advanced account settings and uncheck "Send SIP keep-alives" option. It's a proprietary buggy crap.

Comment: while this is a true statement it doesn't resolve the identified issue.

Comment: at least it solved my problem, # key was not recognized. thanks